# Spring Security - Wildcards/matchers in authorization rules

Tags: java, spring, security, configuration

While configuring the security of my Spring Boot application, I wanted to secure parts of the API depending on the PathVariable that is entered there. My current configuration is as follows:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    //not important

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors();
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers("/api").authenticated()
            .mvcMatchers("/api/TEST").hasAuthority("SCOPE_dep:TEST")
            .and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    }
}
```

In the `api/{PathVariable}` endpoint is the one I want to have customized, making sure that someone with the authority `SCOPE_dep:TEST` can access the `api/TEST` endpoint, someone with `SCOPE_dep:TEST2` authority can access the `api/TEST2` endpoint, even allowing more than one such endpoint for a user which has multiple of these authorities.

Is there a way to do this by using a type of wildcard/matcher that I'm unaware of, or is the only possibility to hardcode all these different authorities?

Comment: @Archmede have same issue with you, donnot want to write a lot of dummy code, have you solved the problem yet

Comment: @ManManYu I didn't ask this question but you're probably better off solving the problem with something like `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthorityOrWildcardAction('')")` at the controller level